# How to make Dynamic Where in Prisma js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

I want to make where it can be dynamic according to what is inputted by the frontend, here I have mapped the data and the object results are like this

```
{ id: '2', name: 'yuhu' }
```

the key of id and name can be dynamic depending on the frontend, i tried by adding loop object inside where but it doesn't work because of `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'`

does anyone have another solution to create dynamic filter

this is my fullcode

```
  class ProductRepository {
  static async getAllProduct(skipPage, takePage, filter) {
    let a = await Product.findMany({
      skip: parseInt(skipPage) - 1,
      take: parseInt(takePage),
      where: {
        for (const property in filter) {
          console.log(`${property}: ${filter[property]}`);
        }
        
        // loop filter here
        // filter = { id: '2', name: 'yuhu' }

      },
      include: {
        gallery: true,
      },
    });
    console.log("hasil product ", a)
    return a
  }

  static async getAllRow() {
    return await Product.count();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript/TypeScript syntax is incorrect. If you are using TypeScript in your project, you can inspect the `where` property of the `findMany` call to see that `where` expects an object, and you are not passing it an object. You cannot use a `for` loop in the declaration of an object. If you want to dynamically construct the `where` call based on the contents of `filter`, you would want to do something like this:

```js
const constructedWhere = Object.keys(filter).reduce((aggregate, property) => {
  aggregate[property] = filter[property];
  return aggregate;
}, {});
let a = await Product.findMany({
    skip: parseInt(skipPage) - 1,
    take: parseInt(takePage),
    where: constructedWhere,
    include: {
        gallery: true,
    },
});
```

Whatever `filter` is, it also has to provide filters that conform to the expected input for `Product.findMany.where`. Again, this is where Prisma's emitted TypeScript comes in handy - if you are using an editor with some sort of Intellisense, you can click into the TypeScript definition to see what shape `where` is expected to be in so you know exactly how to calculate it.